# Удаление обратного слэша python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строка:

```
s = "\\xd0\\xbf\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x82"
```

Нужно сделать её такой:

```
s = "\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82"
```

Пробовал с помощью replace но результата нет.

```
s = "\\xd0\\xbf\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x82"
s = s.replace("\\\\", "\\")
```

Comment: а как вы такую строку получаете?

Comment: Скорее всего, эту строку вы видели в консоли, но, я думаю, что на самом деле она имеет один слеш, но в консоли было показано ее строковое представление, а в нем принято экранировать слеши

Comment: Я получаю именно эту строку, мне нужно чтобы там был один слеш потому что эту строку нужно переконвертировать в байты

Comment: В консоли когда я печатаю строку с одним слешем вылезают непонятные символы, мне так и надо

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(f"'{s}'")`.

Answer (score 3):

Я подозреваю вас, что вы вашим вопросом совершили [«Ошибку молотка» («Ошибку XY»)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/233990).

Точнее, вам не интересно, как из строки `s` сделать строку только с одними обратными слешми, вам нужно получить из ней строку `"привет"`.

И так:

```
result = s.encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

---

*Примечание 1:*

Уберите последнюю часть (`.decode('utf8')`) чтобы вы получили приблизительно то, что вы сформулировали в вашем вопросе - но не в виде *строки*, а в виде *последовательности байтов:*

> ```
> b'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
> ```

---

*Примечание 2:*

Этa последняя часть (`.decode('utf8')`) бы была достаточной, когда бы не было первичной ошибки - метода, которым вы получили вашу оригинальную строку `s`:

**Вы читали файл в текстовом, а не в бинарном режиме.**

Когда бы вы его читали в *бинарном* режиме, вы бы получили *последовательность байтов*

```
p = b'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
```

и нужно бы было сделать *только последний шаг:* `p.decode("utf8")`.

---

*Обяснение:*

- **Строки** возможно только **кодировать** (в последовательность байтов)
  (например для переноса в другой компьютер через сеть).
- **Последовательности байтов** возможно только **декодировать** (в строки)
  (например после получение другим компьютером через сеть.)

Поэтому *цепочка повторного кодирования и декодирования.*

Сначала нужно вашу строку закодировать в байтовую последовательность кодеком лatin-1, чтобы было возможно применить декодировку unicode_escape - см. [Text Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings).

Но и результат нужно опять кодировать, чтобы эго было возможно декодировать как UTF-8 (потому, что UTF-8 кодировка оригинального текста).

Comment: `Но и результат нужно опять кодировать, чтобы эго было возможно декодировать как UTF-8 (т.к. в Питоне 3 все строки в Юникоде UTF-8).` - не поэтому нужно декодировать как UTF-8, а потому что исходно этот набор байтов - строка в UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

*Вам не нужно того, что вы сформулировали в вашем вопросе, просто сделайте*

```
s = "\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82"
print(s)
```

*чтобы вы в этом убедились — выводится чудесная строка*

> ```
> Ð¿ÑÐ¸Ð²ÐµÑ
> ```

Вам не нужна **строка**

```
"\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82"
```

- (т.к. это строка из 12 символов: `\xd0`, `\xbf`, `\xd1`, ..., `\x82`, представленных в виде экранированных последовательностей, 2 из них неизобразительные (`\x80` и `\0x82`)

а **последовательность байтов**

```
b"\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82"
```

(см. мой [другой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1173671/233990)).

---

*Применчание:*

- `\xd0` это Юникод `U+00D0` `Ð` ([LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ETH](https://unicode-table.com/en/#00D0)),
- `\xbf` это Юникод `U+00BF` `¿` ([INVERTED QUESTION MARK](https://unicode-table.com/en/#00BF)),
- . . .
- `\x80` это Юникод `U+0080` Control Character - PADDING CHARACTER (PAD)
- . . .
- `\x82` это Юникод `U+0082` Control Character - BREAK PERMITTED HERE (BPH))

---

---

Но всё равно, я отвечу вам на ваш вопрос, *как бы вы искренне хотели того, что вы написали:*

Существует разница между тем,

- что вы в строке **видите** (`\\`) и
- тем, что в строке **действительно находится** (`\`).

Примените функцию `print()`:

```
s = "\\xd0\\xbf\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x82"
print(s)
```

> ```
> \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

Строковые константы возможно писать в разных видах, для вас интересны эти:

1. просто в кавычках или апострофах: `"что-то"`,
2. с буквой `r` перед ними: `r"что-то"`.
   (Буква `r` значит **raw** - сырая строка.)

Разница между ними только одна:

- в первом случае символ `\` интерпретируется как *начало экранированной последовательности* (которая в итоге представляет собой только **один** символ)
- а в другом случае нет — он будет дословно символом `\`.

Примером экранированной последовательности может быть `\n` - она означает **один** (специальный) символ (переход на новую строку), хотя он написан как **два** символа: `\` и  `n.`

Подобным видом экранированная последовательность `\\` обозначает **один** символ: `\`, хотя он написан как **два** символа: `\` и `\`.

Значит, вашу строку — одну и ту же самую — возможно писать как

```
s = "\\xd0\\xbf\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x82"
```

или

```
s = r"\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82"
```

В обоих случаях получите ту же самую строку (длины 48).

Comment: Мне как раз таки нужно сделать строку с одним слешем, мне не нужно получить слово привет, мне нужна строка только с одним слешем. После этого я уже перевожу ее в байты(делать я это умею)

Comment: Я получаю строку из json, оно почему то экранирует все обратные слеши, а мне надо записать все байты в новый файл, но из-за того что там два слеша, а не один, файл получается неправильным(отсутствуют переходы строк, табуляции, они записываются как текст)

Comment: @ARTEGOSERUM, вы вероятно не поняли, что в вашей строке фактически нет двойных обратных слешов, может быть, что мой ответ для вас не совсем ясный. Ваша оригинальная строка, а строка, которую вы хотите ин ней получить, совсем разные — длина первой 48, длина второй только 12. У них только очень подобные формы, в которых их Питон изображает. Сделайте `print()` одной и другой, как вам я советовал.

Comment: *«Я получаю строку из json»* - тогда бы было угодно **добавить это в ваш вопрос** (вместе с методом, каким вы из него получили вашу строку и вместе с JSON файлом). Опять [проблема молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/233990).

Comment: @ARTEGOSERUM, я попробовал более убедительно вам объяснить, в чем дело, и расширил мой ответ.